# TagLib sharp not editing artist

Tags: c#, mp3, taglib, id3, taglib-sharp

I'm trying to save new artist and title id3 tags into tracks. Loading tags from tracks working good, also editing title for track is working fine. But when i try to edit **performer** *(artist)* it didn't change anything. Here is the code

```
public void renameID3(string artist,string title)
{ 
   using (TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(FInfo.FullName))
        {
            f.Tag.Artists[0] = artist; //Both of them are not ...
            f.Tag.Performers[0] = artist; //working


            f.Tag.Title = title; //This works fine
            f.Save();
        }
  }
```

Plus I looked the definiton of **FirstPerformer** and **FirstPerformer** members of TagLib class but they don't have any set method.
Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stuck with the very same problem. Found that clearing `Performers` first makes it work as intended:

```
using(TagLib.File tlFile = TagLib.File.Create(newFileName)){
    //tlFile.Tag.Performers = new []{translateDict[author]}; //doesn't work
    tlFile.Tag.Performers = null; //clearing out performers
    tlFile.Tag.Performers = new []{translateDict[author]}; //works now
    tlFile.Save();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `=null` step. The problem is that Performers, et al return *new* array so editing it doesn't make changes to the underlying data structure. It should really return an IEnumerable<String> but I was young and reckless.

Comment: @BrianNickel Can you please take alook at question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414734/cant-add-image-keywords-if-there-were-no-keywords-to-begin-with-taglib-sharp/35421960#35421960

Answer (score 1):

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(yourFile);
f.Tag.AlbumArtists = new string[] { "Artist 1", "Artist 2", ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create (fname);
file.Tag.Performers = new String[1] { artist };
file.Save();
```