# TagLib is not saving ID3 Tags

Tags: c#, mp3, taglib, id3, taglib-sharp

I have a problem with TagLibSharp v2.2.0.
I’ve been looking for solutions on the internet for quite some time. In the process I found things like e.g. which can force TagLib to save in a specific version

```
TagLib. Id3v2. Day. DefaultVersion = 3;
TagLib. Id3v2. Day. ForceDefaultVersion = true;
```

Or how it may be that the file has a .mp3 extension, but is not a proper Mp3 file. I’ve looked into a hex editor, and my file starts at 49 44 33, so it should also be a proper Mp3 file.

```
TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.DefaultVersion = 3;
TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.ForceDefaultVersion = true;

var Mp3File = TagLib.File.Create(customPath, TagLib.ReadStyle.Average);

Mp3File.Tag.Performers = new string[] { "Billy Bob" };
Mp3File.Tag.Title = "Silly Job";

//If I display a messagebox at the point here, which shows the Performers and Title of the Mp3File
//it shows the correct text (Billy Bob, Silly Job)
MessageBox.Show($"{Mp3File.Tag.Performers}, {Mp3File.Tag.Title}");

Mp3File.Save();
Mp3File.Dispose();
```

When I run the code, there is no exception, but when I look at the file details, nothing has changed.
Does anyone have any idea what this could be about?

Comment: As it stands your code won't compile as Perfromers is a string __array__.! - Using the current TagLib from NuGet `Mp3File.Tag.Performers = "Billy Bob";`should read `Mp3File.Tag.Performers = new string[] { "Billy Bob" };`. Other than that your code works fine here. Update: But this indeed does make a difference, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292142/taglib-sharp-not-editing-artist)

Comment: Oh, sorry in my code at performers is a string array. Thats not the problem.

Comment: OK, it runs fine here both on mp3 and flac files. What's with the `DefaultVersion` stuff you mentionend. I didn't use it nor do I know how and why I would..?

Comment: I tried it without it, then I added it and just left it in. This is because Windows can probably only "use" a certain version of the tags, and this then ensures that this version is also used. But I don't remember exactly.

Comment: Perhaps it is still useful to know that the Mp3 files are downloaded with YoutubeExplode. There then with AudioOnly (). WithHighestBitRate ()

Comment: As a test I would do a few test with files from other sources. _I tried it without it, then I added it and just left it in_ Hm. Here those two lines simply do not compile..!?

Comment: Which two lines do you mean?
Mp3File.Save();
Mp3File.Dispose();
Or which?

Comment: `TagLib. Id3v2. Day. DefaultVersion = 3;
TagLib. Id3v2. Day. ForceDefaultVersion = true;` - BTW: Did you find anything in the way of real documentation for TagLib Sharp? I mean a comprehensive list of its classes with properties, events and methods?

Comment: Okay, i tried it with a mp3 file from another source. It also didn't work

Comment: OK, I just noticed that the 2 lines seem to be a typo with Day for Tag, right?

Comment: If you mean the blank character ? yeah